# iOS IMAP library

Tags: iphone, ios, imap

I am trying to find a way how to search for some string on an IMAP server in iOS.

Right up until now I have failed with my task.

Do you have any ideas or pointers how to achieve this?

Regardz,
Mladjo

Comment: You will need to post the code you have so far and then someone can make other suggestion to your question.

Answer (score 5):

There is the [MailCore](http://libmailcore.com/) Cocoa framework, which provides a nice wrapper for the libetpan library.  An iOS version of this is available through the [reMail open source project](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/).  The code there should provide a good starting point for dealing with IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [libetpan](http://www.etpan.org/libetpan/index.html)?
I don't know if it can search on a server but it does IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3dJLxjBsHj-YkdqVDhVWG1zOGM/edit?usp=sharing

This is an existing library but modified like you can fire the delete command , search command, store command, you can set the flag of imap message you can reset the imap message flags etc. 
Try this